# Spring MVC + DataTables 1.10 Parameters binding

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, datatables, datatables-1.10

I'm trying to do a controller that do the Server Side for DataTables.

```
@RequestMapping(value="/grid", method={RequestMethod.GET}, produces= MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    @ResponseBody
    public DataTablesResponse<MyObject> grid(DataTablesRequest dt) {
        return service.getListOfMyObjects();
    }
```

DataTablesRequest.class:

```
public class DataTablesRequest {

    private int draw;
    private int start;
    private int length;

    private Search search;

    private List<Order> order;

    private List<Column> columns;

   //... Getters and setters
}
```

Order.class:

```
public class Order {
    private String column;
    private String dir;
//...getters and setters
}
```

Column.class

```
public class Column {

    private String data;
    private String name;
    private boolean searchable;
    private boolean orderable;
    private Search search;
//...Getters and setters
}
```

Search.class:

```
public class Search {
    private String value;
    private boolean regex;
//...getters and setters
}
```

The problem is that DataTables sends parameters like: column[0][name] and SpringMVC is expecting something like column[0].name.

Is there any way to fix that? How can i bind the parameters of the DataTables to an object?

Comment: I tried to integrate some parts of datatables v1.10.+  into Spring 4, I came up with this https://github.com/joaoevangelista/spring-data-datatables-integration, also have a look at http://dandelion.github.io/datatables/features/ajax/integration-with-spring.html. It's currently not designed for v1.10.+ put might be helpful

Comment: Nice, but this code is missing the problematic part of my issue: The ordering and Columns informations =/

Answer (score 7):

Kind of a late answer, but maybe this would help someone in the future:

In datatables settings, we need to tell jQuery to **not** process data and to send JSON:

```
ajax: {
     url: "/some/url.json"),
     type: "POST",
     data: function (data) {
         return JSON.stringify(data);
     },
     dataType: "json",
     processData: false,
     contentType: 'application/json;charset=UTF-8'
},
```

on the Spring side:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/some/url")
@ResponseBody
public DataTablesResponse<Element> list(@RequestBody final DataTablesRequest dataTablesRequest) {
    // query the DB to get the number of elements (without filtering)
    // and the list of elements (filtered and/or paginated)
    return new DataTablesResponse(numberOfElements, notifications.getTotalElements(), dataTablesRequest.getDraw(), "", listOfElements);
}
```

With the following for `DataTablesRequest` etc (`@Data` is from [lombok](https://projectlombok.org/), javadoc comments are from the official datatables doc.):

```
@Data
public class DataTablesRequest {
    /**
     * Draw counter. This is used by DataTables to ensure that the Ajax returns from server-side processing requests are drawn in sequence by DataTables
     * (Ajax requests are asynchronous and thus can return out of sequence). This is used as part of the draw return parameter (see below).
     */
    private int draw;

    /**
     * Paging first record indicator. This is the start point in the current data set (0 index based - i.e. 0 is the first record).
     */
    private int start;

    /**
     * Number of records that the table can display in the current draw. It is expected that the number of records returned will be equal to this number, unless
     * the server has fewer records to return. Note that this can be -1 to indicate that all records should be returned (although that negates any benefits of
     * server-side processing!)
     */
    private int length;

    /**
     * @see Search
     */
    private Search search;

    /**
     * @see Order
     */
    @JsonProperty("order")
    private List<Order> orders;

    /**
     * @see Column
     */
    private List<Column> columns;
}

@Data
private static class Search {
    /**
     * Global search value. To be applied to all columns which have searchable as true.
     */
    private String value;

    /**
     * <code>true</code> if the global filter should be treated as a regular expression for advanced searching, false otherwise. Note that normally server-side
     * processing scripts will not perform regular expression searching for performance reasons on large data sets, but it is technically possible and at the
     * discretion of your script.
     */
    private boolean regex;
}

@Data
private static class Order {
    /**
     * Column to which ordering should be applied. This is an index reference to the columns array of information that is also submitted to the server.
     */
    private int column;

    /**
     * Ordering direction for this column. It will be <code>asc</code> or <code>desc</code> to indicate ascending ordering or descending ordering,
     * respectively.
     */
    private String dir;
}

@Data
private static class Column {
    /**
     * Column's data source, as defined by columns.data.
     */
    private String data;

    /**
     * Column's name, as defined by columns.name.
     */
    private String name;

    /**
     * Flag to indicate if this column is searchable (true) or not (false). This is controlled by columns.searchable.
     */
    private boolean searchable;


    /**
     * Flag to indicate if this column is orderable (true) or not (false). This is controlled by columns.orderable.
     */
    private boolean orderable;

    /**
     * Search value to apply to this specific column.
     */
    private Search search;

    /**
     * Flag to indicate if the search term for this column should be treated as regular expression (true) or not (false). As with global search, normally
     * server-side processing scripts will not perform regular expression searching for performance reasons on large data sets, but it is technically possible
     * and at the discretion of your script.
     */
    private boolean regex;
}

@Data
public class DataTablesResponse<T> {
    /**
     * The draw counter that this object is a response to - from the draw parameter sent as part of the data request. Note that it is strongly recommended for
     * security reasons that you cast this parameter to an integer, rather than simply echoing back to the client what it sent in the draw parameter, in order
     * to prevent Cross Site Scripting (XSS) attacks.
     */
    private int draw;

    /**
     * Total records, before filtering (i.e. the total number of records in the database)
     * <p/>
     * (NB: I changed this to long)
     */
    private long recordsTotal;

    /**
     * Total records, after filtering (i.e. the total number of records after filtering has been applied - not just the number of records being returned for this
     * page of data).
     * <p/>
     * (NB: I changed this to long)
     */
    private long recordsFiltered;

    /**
     * Optional: If an error occurs during the running of the server-side processing script, you can inform the user of this error by passing back the error message
     * to be displayed using this parameter. Do not include if there is no error.
     */
    private String error;

    /**
     * The data to be displayed in the table. This is an array of data source objects, one for each row, which will be used by DataTables. Note that this parameter's
     * name can be changed using the ajax option's dataSrc property.
     */
    private List<T> data = Lists.newArrayList();
}
```

Comment: Can this be done using GET or POST is easier to implement?

Comment: GET or POST it's your choice, no?

Comment: Yes, but datatables when using GET are passing url which isnt't trivial to parse using `@RequestParams`, etc., this part: &order[0][column]=1&order[0][dir]=desc

Comment: This works, but in ideal scenario, should be a GET, not a POST. This is because this is just a "list" REST operation... That's why my question was posted in the first place. With a POST, the problem in the question doesn't exists...

Answer (score 1):

How about to implement HandlerMethodArgumentResolver, please refer to https://github.com/rakurakupg/springmvc-jquerydatatables-example

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue and below worked for me.
Try adding `@JsonProperty` to each property in every parameter binding class e.g. `@JsonProperty(value = "draw")`. This way Jackson maps it fine with the JSON sent from DataTable. In my case, I was getting below JSON

```
{   
"draw":1,
"columns":[
    {"data":0,"name":"","searchable":true,"orderable":false,"search":{"value":"","regex":false}},
    {"data":1,"name":"","searchable":true,"orderable":false,"search":{"value":"","regex":false}}],
"order":[],
"start":0,
"length":-1,
"search":{"value":"","regex":false}
```

}

Also there is a need to have the empty constructor defined for  `DataTablesRequest`, `Column`,`Order` and `Search`. 
If you do not want to have the default constructor, you can add it like below,

```
public Search(@JsonProperty("value") String value,@JsonProperty("regex") String regex) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Forgot to mention, I am using Jackson 1.9.9 and DataTable 1.10.

Comment: That didn't worked out. I've tried to put the annotation on all properties but it didn't work. The problem is the Spring binding.

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this for me was to send the request as JSON by following the instructions here: [ASP.net jQuery DataTables](https://css3rocks.wordpress.com/2014/05/22/asp-net-using-jquery-datatables-1-10-plugin-and-ajax/)

Essentially just change the JS on your page to something like this:

```
'ajax': {
    'url': 'serverSideTableProviderPage',
    'type': 'POST',
    'data':function(data)
     {
       return data = JSON.stringify(data);
     }
},
```